# Ionic tabs don’t fit on Android physical devices but fit on emulators and iPhones

Tags: ionic-framework

I am migrating an old ionic angular App. I have the App running on iPhones and both iPhone emulator through Xcode and Android emulator through Android Studio. But when I deploy that to Android physical device from the same Android Studio, the ionic tabs don’t fit in the tab bar on the Android physical device. I have 7 tabs with icons and about half tab on each side gets clipped off with 5 of them showing in between. I have tried this on a Samsung 22 phone and also on an old Xiaomi device - both have the same problem.

I have tried to search around for this issue but couldn’t find anything so far.

My ionic info output is below

```
Ionic:

Ionic CLI : 7.1.1 (/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v20.2.0/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 5.6.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.2.18
@angular-devkit/schematics : 12.2.18
@angular/cli : 12.2.18
@ionic/angular-toolkit : 5.0.3

Capacitor:

Capacitor CLI : 3.9.0
@capacitor/android : 3.9.0
@capacitor/core : 3.9.0
@capacitor/ios : 3.9.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI : 12.0.0 (cordova-lib@12.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0, browser 6.0.0, ios 6.2.0
Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 5 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.15.4
native-run (update available: 1.7.3) : 1.7.1

System:

ios-sim : 8.0.2
NodeJS : v20.2.0 (/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v20.2.0/bin/node)
npm : 9.6.6
OS : macOS Unknown
Xcode : Xcode 15.0 Build version 15A240d
```

Android Studio is Giraffe 2022.3.1 Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10406996, built on June 28, 2023

Not quite sure how to address/fix this issue. Appreciate any help/pointers.

Thanks,
Sanjay.

PS: I also posted this on the ionicframework forum and waiting for any guidance
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-tabs-dont-fit-on-android-physical-devices-but-fit-on-emulators-and-iphones/237611